# what if i swap an element with -1 index of array

Tags: c++

```
  // ques-move all negative ele to one side
    
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int n;
    cin >> n;
    
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        int j=-1;
        int pivot = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(arr[i]<pivot){
                swap(arr[i],arr[j])
                i++;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }`
```

if we swap 1st index with -1 th index if it is negative then what will happen will a garbage value take place at arr[1]

Comment: Since there is no element at index `-1` - the program, which accesses array at such an index, would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Worst case scenario:  the program appears to work.  Best case scenario:  compiler warns you about the mistake.  Likely scenario:  program doesn't compile because it is using variable length arrays (which are not part of C++).

Comment: but this is answer of question

Comment: pointers do have a definitive subtraction behavior.  Array access usually ties into this.  Accessing addresses that may have anything (including nothing) at them is where things get dicey.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array outside of its bounds of 0 to n-1 is undefined behavior.  The most likely outcome is a garbage value, but literally anything could happen - your program could crash, you could erase your entire disk drive, or [demons could fly from your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).